# Creating a Block view for Other nearby stores

Tags: views, commerce, location

I want to create a  block to display all nearby commerce stores . I have setup  a view of type commerce store . Inside the View  I have displayed fields.

In contextual filter "WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE"  Provide default value  -> Raw value from the url ,path component = 2 and  Use path alias  . The path on which this is displayed is mysitename.com/store/store:id . and under more exclude this display .

Under Filter Criteria - Commerce Store: geofield (field_geofield) - proximity . What value should be "selected from source of origin point" and what should be passed in "From " value.